# Где грамматическая основа?

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где грамматическая основа в предложениях? 
Это не привычка, это что-то другое, большее. (Сомневаюсь, входят ли в сказуемое "другое, большее.)
Он ложился спать рано. (Я думаю, что сказуемое - ложился, а спать - обстоятельство.)
Было совсем по-вечернему. (Я думаю, что сказуемое - было по-вечернему.)
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не привычка, это что-то другое, большее. Сказуемое - что-то другое, большее. Скорее всего, это нерасчленимое сочетание.

Он ложился спать рано. Спать - обстоятельство цели.

Было совсем по-вечернему. Сказуемое - было совсем  по-вечернему. Частицу надо включить в сказуемое.

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то, что ответ принят, всё же отвечу, потому что там 2 ошибки, девочке будет медвежья услуга от сайта.

1. Согласна. Это - подлежащее, не привычка - сказуемое; это - подлежащее, что-то другое, большее - два однородных сказуемых. "Что-то другое" - слитное словосочетание, большее-уточняющее сказуемое.
2. Он ложился спать рано. - Сказуемое - ложился спать. - составное глагольное, в данном значении "ложился" = начальная стадия процесса сна. Главное сообщение (рема) не то, что он принял лежачее положение, а то, что он начинает процесс сна. Именно этого сказуемого в справочниках не нашла, а вот "Девочка Вера стала ложиться спать" в справочнике приводится как пример осложнённого (трёхкомпонентного сказуемого). Осложнение "стала" убираем - остаётся неосложнённое "ложиться спать" - это в учебнике для филфака.
3. Было совсем по-вечернему. - "было по-вечернему" - составное именное сказуемое безличного предложения. "Совсем" - это не частица, это наречие = очень (наречие) - обстоятельство.

Comment: Всё очень спорно, хотя вопросы сложные. 1) Странно один член однородного ряда относить к уточняющему сказуемому, а другой включать в слитное словосочетание. 2) Бросился бежать - это точно "начал бежать", а пошел спать, лег спать, прилег отдохнуть - всё очень похожие варианты. 3) Было по-вечернему - так, кажется не скажешь. Такие наречия, как совсем,  вполне могут играть роль частицы (с наречиями это случается). Я не настаиваю на правильности своих ответов, но считать их очевидными ОШИБКАМИ тоже не стала бы.

Comment: Здесь "что-то" относится к обоим сказуемым, только во втором оно пропущено ради экономии(что-то другое, что-то большее), так бывает,общим членом может быть даже глагол-связка: надо петь и плясать,что-то родное и до боли знакомое.

пошел спать, прилег отдохнуть - похожие варианты, но ложился спать, лёг спать - совсем другое, сейчас это иногда воспринимается как фразеологизм. У слова "легли" есть даже полноправное значение "лечь спать"- "Дети уже легли" - и никто не сомневается, что они легли спать, а не приняли лежачее положение.

Comment: Людмила, стала ложиться спать - я бы отнес к СГС, а не к осложнённому трёхкомпонентному сказуемому. 

>Ср.: Он захотел начать обедать;Он захотел стать пожарным - здесь все части равноправны. Это осложненное трехкомпонентное сказуемое. 

>Он был готов попытаться начать работать пожарным.осложненное многокомпонентное сказуемое

**А вот ложиться спать - цельное словосочетание и вряд ли его можно отнести СО трехкомпонентному сказуемому**.

Comment: А "совсем", действительно, бывает частицей, вернее, некоторые учёные называют частицей с усилительно-количественным значением - совсем не, вовсе не: он совсем (очень-наречие)неинтересный человек// он совсем не интересный = вовсе не (частица)интересный=отнюдь не интересный, кто-то их называет наречиями-частицами, но "совсем по-вечернему"-это в значении "очень", "в высшей степени"-наречие меры и  степени

Comment: Серж,я взяла пример из институтского учебника.Насчёт "я бы отнес к СГС"-оно и есть СГС,только осложнённое. Если Вы имеете в виду слитное сочетание, я искала его во всех фразеологических словарях(мне тоже так показалось), такого фразеологизма не нашла, только в русско-английском называют идиомой при переводе. Но и считать СПАТЬ обстоятельством нельзя:пошёл (куда?)спать-понятно, что обстоятельство, а ложусь (куда? зачем? )- как-то глуповато, они связаны, и очень тесно, лексическое значение сочетания содержится именно в инфинитиве, а "ложился"-вспомогательный глагол.

Comment: Людмила, ''спать'' действительно не обстоятельство. Людмила, в словарях ''ложиться''  - полнозначный глагол.

Comment: Осложненное еще может быть, но называть трехкомпонентным вряд ли можно.

Comment: Серж, Вы меня удивляете, посчитайте, 3 компонента:1-стала,2- ложиться,3- спать, а ложится спать-двухкомпонентное. Всё просто. В чём вопрос?

Comment: В грамматике выделяется  осложненное СГС: хотел начать работать, не должен бояться возражать, намерен согласиться продолжать искать. Но все элементы вспомогательной части имеют модальный или фазовый характер. Ложиться спать - это лечь в кровать с намерением (целью) заснуть. Можно просто лечь отдохнуть. Получается, что "ложиться спать" - это прецедент какой-то. Есть ли где описание подобных вариантов, есть ли вообще такие варианты?

Comment: Вы правы, Вера: Но все элементы вспомогательной части имеют модальный или фазовый характер. Но в предложении ложиться спать - ложиться - не является фазисным. Но в то же время вряд ли можно сказать, что глагол "ложиться" - выражает цель.

Comment: Цель выражает глагол "спать". Можно просто лечь, например: я лег почитать книгу, я лег, чтобы притвориться больным. А можно сказать: я лег спать (лег, чтобы уснуть и пробыть некоторое время в состоянии сна).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал, что сказуемое – "ложился спать"

Comment: Поехали встречать, отправился помочь, приехал погостить, остался ночевать, прилег отдохнуть - это примеры из учебника по грамматике, где инфинитив является обстоятельством цели.

Comment: По-моему, эти примеры совсем другое дело. Не представляю, как можно отделить "ложился" от "спать". "Прилег отдохнуть" – другое дело.

Кстати, а есть примеры, в которых инфинитив – часть сказуемого?

Comment: Ничего похожего нет. В составном глагольном сказуемом первый глагол или модальный, или фазовый. Еще утверждается, что при глаголах движения или положения инфинитив является обстоятельством цели.

Comment: Почему ж ничего похожего? Бросился бежать - сост. глаг. сказуемое. Слова "начал" нет, но это начало действия. Вас,Niemand, чутьё как и всегда, не подвело. Ложился спать - сказуемое/

Answer (score 0):

ложился спать - простое глагольное сказуемое. обстоятельство здесь очевидно - рано(когда?).

ПГС может быть выражено несколькими сказуемыми. Напр.:

> Он будет долго вспоминать о былом (будущее сложное)
>
> Пусть звезды вечно освещают твой долгий-долгий зимний путь (повелительное наклонение).
>
> Пойду прогуляюсь (сочетание разных глаголов в одинаковой форме).

Дополнение 
Ответ Граммы.ру

> В учебнике допущена явная ошибка. В предложении "Девочка Вера стала ложиться спать" сказуемое не может быть квалифицировано как трехчленное. Для трехчленного сказуемого характерно использование в качестве первых двух компонентов вспомогательных глаголов (фазовых и/или модальных) и связочных глаголов различной семантики. Иными словами, трехчленное сказуемое - это осложненный вариант составного глагольного или составного именного сказуемого. Например: "Друг решил начать работать" (исх. структура: "Друг начал работать"); "Друг решил стать космонавтом" (исх. структура: "Друг стал космонавтом"). Именно поэтому некоторые лингвисты отказываются использовать сам термин "трехчленное (трехкомпонентное) сказуемое", предпочитая термины "осложненное составное глагольное сказуемое" и "осложненное составное именное сказуемое. 
> Если обратиться к Вашему примеру, то исходной структурой будет предложение ***"Девочка Вера ложится спать".*** В данном случае наиболее убедительным будет отнесение к сказуемому только слова ***"ложится";*** слово "спать" квалифицируется как ***обстоятельство цели (целевой инфинитив)***. Даже если всю группу ***"ложиться спать" отнести к сказуемому, она не образует составное глагольное сказуемое, так как глагол "ложиться" лишен вспомогательного характера, не имея ни модального, ни фазового значения.*** Таким образом, мы будем вынуждены  считать "ложиться спать" своеобразным глагольным фразеологизмом вроде "пойти погулять" (Я пойду погуляю), такие фразеологизмы считаются осложненной формой простого глагольного сказуемого (=Я погуляю)***.***
> ***Итак, независимо от того, включать ли в состав сказуемого слово "спать" или нет, в предложении "Девочка Вера стала ложиться спать" сказуемое является составным глагольным.***

Comment: Серж, я тоже сначала рассматривала вариант ПГС, но не нашла там ничего подходящего. В ПГС существуют устойчивые обороты вида прийти в себя, впасть в уныние, проявить заботу, но у них вторая часть именная. Также выделяют осложненные формы ПГС: ждет не дождется, ходит и ходит, сказал так сказал; сидел, сидел (повторы) и сижу читаю, пойду посмотрю (движение или положение, второй глагол в личной форме).